# Comment Author Name In Reply Form

Tags: comments, author

I have enabled comment replies in my blog. Lets say there is a comment Nick has written... when I'm gonna reply, I want to display a message "Replying to Nick" in the reply's form header. Anyone knows how? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The WordPress function [comment_form_title](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form_title) works only for users with Javascript disabled or pages without the comment-reply.js JavaScript loaded.

WordPress may not fix this limitation at all
Two tickets have been opened before and closed without fix.
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10084
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/8639

However I managed to get it work for the default twentyeleven theme by using some dirty fixes.
Here is the code you may use as plugin.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Comment Form Title Fix
 * Plugin URI: 
 * Description: WordPress provides comment_form_title function to displays text based on comment reply status. This only affects users with Javascript disabled or pages without the comment-reply.js JavaScript loaded. This plugin provides dirty fix to remove this limitation.
 * Author: tamilsweet
 * Author URI: http://tamilg.in/
 * Version: 0.1
 * Limitation: Tested only with default comment form.
 */

define('CFTF_REPLY_TEXT', 'Leave a Reply');
define('CFTF_REPLY_TO_TEXT', 'Leave a Reply to %s');

// Enable jquery
add_action('init', 'my_script');
function my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}

add_filter('comment_reply_link', 'cftf_reply_link');
function cftf_reply_link($link) {
    global $comment;

    $author = get_comment_author();
    $replytext = sprintf( CFTF_REPLY_TO_TEXT, $author );

    $link = str_replace("onclick='return", "onclick='cftf_update_title(\"${replytext}\"); return", $link);
    return $link;
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'cftf_javascript');
function cftf_javascript() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function cftf_update_title(title) {
    var temp = jQuery("#reply-title :first").html();
    jQuery("#reply-title").html(title + '<small>' +  temp + '</small>');
}

jQuery("#cancel-comment-reply-link").live('click', function() {
    var title = "<?php echo CFTF_REPLY_TEXT;?>";
    var temp = jQuery("#reply-title :first").html();
    jQuery("#reply-title").html(title + '<small>' +  temp + '</small>');
});
</script>
<?php
}
```

Remember it may not work with all themes.

**Update:**
To make it work with the custom theme @Arg Geo uses.
Replace the function cftf_javascript() as below

```
function cftf_javascript() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function cftf_update_title(title) {
    jQuery("#reply-title").html(title);
}

jQuery("#cancel-comment-reply-link").live('click', function() {
    var title = "<?php echo CFTF_REPLY_TEXT;?>";
    jQuery("#reply-title").html(title);
});
</script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately didn't work...

Comment: I suppose you didn't activate the plugin!

Comment: I activated it tamilsweet!

Comment: Did you test it with "TwentyEleven" theme without customization ??

Comment: No, I tested it in my theme.

Comment: So, you didn't read the answer properly. No wonder that it didn't work.

Comment: Update #reply-title and #cancel-comment-reply-link based on your theme element ids.

Comment: "Remember it may not work with all themes." When I said "Unfortunately didn't work..." I was referring to my theme and not in general.

Comment: Well "Unfortunately didn't work..." is different from "Unfortunately didn't work with my theme..."

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am using a custom theme I created. Excuse me.

Comment: Update. After replacing #reply-title etc with the classes I use seems to almost work. It says "Leave a Reply to Anonymousnull"

Comment: Provide the HTML of the response title. eg <h3 id="reply-title">Leave a Reply <small><a rel="nofollow" id="cancel-comment-reply-link" href="/public/sosiale/?p=18#respond" style="display:none;">Cancel reply</a></small></h3>

Comment: Where to put this piece of code?

Comment: You dont have to put that in your code. I'm asking you to give yours. Just open any of the single page and in the html source you can find something similar to that. I want to have look at the element with the id #reply-title or the one you use.

Comment: <h3>Leave a Reply</h3>
 
<div class="cancel-comment-reply">
<small><a rel="nofollow" id="cancel-comment-reply-link" href="/?p=1255&amp;cpage=2#respond" style="display:none;">Click here to cancel reply.</a></small>
</div>

Comment: Added replacement function for cftf_javascript in answer based on your html. Check it out.

Comment: Now I get always "Leave a Reply to Anonymous".

Comment: Can you give your blog url ??

Comment: It's not online, I am working on localhost with wamp server.

Answer (score 1):

As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers.

In the code tamilsweet provided replace:

```
jQuery("#cancel-comment-reply-link").live('click', function() {
```

**with:**

```
jQuery("#respond").on('click', '#cancel-comment-reply-link', function() {
```